# Applying for a Schengen Visa as a visiting student in UK

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

I am an exchange student in the UK for January- May 2015. I have a Pakistani passport. My visa here ends July 1. I want to do an Europe tour, or at least go to one or two countries, after my exams end in May but there's a strict restriction- If you are applying from the UK, your UK residence permit must be valid for three months after your trip ends.

I understand the logic behind this- so people don't seek asylum there. But, what if I am only here for a short time? Can I show my return ticket back home to Qatar (where I live)? I have to go back and complete my studies anyways. This is tricky because only a very small number of people can apply for a Schengen visa from the UK and only during an exact time, eh?

Comment: The idea is that only long-term UK residents who can/will come back to the UK at the end of their Schengen trip can apply there. It's not a very small number of people but indeed does not include many students/temporary workers who might want to add a Schengen trip at the end of their UK stay and are not allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. There're always clear instructions that your visa should be valid for 3 months & this, you've already mentioned. So, my recommendation is, go back to Qatar & apply Schengen visa.